# Why does cancelling a copy-operation take (long) time?

Tags: windows-7

Scenario: I'm copying a couple of large files from a DVD onto my desktop (Windows 7 Pro, in case that matters). After a while I realize that it is going to take too long time, and I press "cancel". The copy dialog changes and says "Canceling...", and then nothing happens for a long time -- several minutes, long enough for my patience to run out.

Why does it take time at all to "cancel" a copy-operation? What is the OS doing or waiting for?

Comment: It's un-copying.  On NTFS that involves some work.

Comment: Why? What does it do?

Comment: @artistoex - "Post the source code"? This isn't Stack Overflow, why should there be any source code in this question?

Comment: @artistoex: This isn't code-related. It's with the Windows OS. I've observed this on Windows Vista & 7. Just a question though... Do you use Windows anyway?

Comment: @artistoex: Why would you need the source code when you can read the assembly? And since when is it problematic to draw conclusions from observing behavior?

Comment: It should be clear that there are thousands of possible reasons for that behavior.  It depends which system calls are involved; if the syscalls block or if non-blocking alternatives are chosen;  how the threads involved are synchronized, etc., etc.  I'm sure it's not with the kernel.  The desktop or shell or whatever you want to call it, has no more privileges than any other user program.  So for that matter there is no difference between the explorer stucking or any other program.   Besides that, I've never heard of something like "uncopying" taking perceivable amounts time.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: is there a theory (maybe links) for this, or is it based on experience? I haven't been able to find _any_ info on why NTFS would 'un-copying' slower than FAT or anything else

Comment: Even if there was something like a massive uncopy action, the explanation is absolutely contrary to how operating systems and applications interact with one another.  Why should the program wait for the kernel do its stuff?  So it can report possible errors?  "Sorry the files will be kept forever--they could not be uncopied".

Comment: Most probably, if a copy fails for some reason it would be glad to know the files are still present as only a part of files might in some cases cause corruption if you later come across the files (or a program uses them) and you don't know that they are only partially copied. It also allows you to know whether you can turn off your computer or not or whether it is still busy with them. All I/O calls except these that drivers directly execute outside the scope of Windows and perahps even the kernel can be inspected, so this is observable behavior and there aren't many reasons for this.

Comment: For one person, this may go intended. But as configurations differ in most cases it might be that there's a virus scanner or something along those lines in place, or perhaps a Search Indexer on a drive with a ton of files; which might a reasonable impact on deletion...

Comment: @jay - I don't know *why* this happens (in any detail), but I know it happens.

Comment: Seems like it doens't want to leave a junky partial file laying around, so it cleans up after itself and finishes off the file it's working on.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx It has to wait for the kernel to interrupt the copy. After that  the copy gets deleted.

Comment: If this is happening only with this particular disc, then the issue is a partially corrupted file. A cancellation of file copying does not take much time. Or incase of a slow hard drive vs large file, that can also be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most people would give an uneducated explanation to this, which is why I'm not going to explain this.

You should see this for yourself, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) allows you to see in detail what I/O is happening! This allows you to confirm whether it's doing something like "uncopying", whether the virus scanner is part of the lengthy cancellation and so on; try filtering down to the source and destination path such that you don't get a lot of irrelevant information.

I can't / won't copy any results at the moment; so, it is left as an exercise to the interested reader...

Comment: But how will you distinguish copy from uncopy?  That's my bet: The OS it is still copying.  The UI cannot cancel the copy action all by it self.  It has to wait for the OS to invoke the [callback routine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449407(v=vs.85).aspx).  Meanwhile it just shows 'Deleting...'

Comment: @artistoex: These are different I/O operations and are thus easily distinguishable.

Comment: really? What kind of I/O operations are they?

Comment: @TomWijsman -- Maybe you could look for us, since you know what to look for.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Seems like you're not interested at all, since you won't take a look for yourself. Process Monitor does not work on Gentoo Linux as far as I know; but well, I already know this out of experience but yet you are the one that's non-believing and actually trying out the application is much better than attempting to believe any random statement made on the subject even if it were a copy and paste from the application in question. Don't be lazy and give it a go yourself... Stack Exchange is about learning, if I need to do your homework then you'll not learn a thing. ;)